# Unable to start monetdb using mserver5

Tags: server, monetdb

I have an existing monetdb installation and a `dbfarm`. I want to change the number of threads being used by monetdb as specified in this (https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Guide/Multicores) docs page. It looks like we need to start monetdb using `mserver5` instead of `monetdbd` to be able to set this parameter. So, I tried the following command:

`mserver5 --dbpath=dbfarm/voc/ --set mapi_port=50000`

```
 BBPdiskscan: unexpected file log.6, leaving /home/mskd/dbfarm/voc/bat/sql_logs/sql.
 BBPdiskscan: unexpected file BBP.dir, leaving /home/mskd/dbfarm/voc/bat/bat/BACKUP.
 # MonetDB 5 server v11.27.13 "Jul2017-SP4"
 # Serving database 'voc', using 8 threads
 # Compiled for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/64bit with 128bit integers
 # Found 31.301 GiB available main-memory.
 # Copyright (c) 1993 - July 2008 CWI.
 # Copyright (c) August 2008 - 2018 MonetDB B.V., all rights reserved
 # Visit https://www.monetdb.org/ for further information
 # Listening for connection requests on mapi:monetdb://127.0.0.1:50000/
 # MonetDB/SQL module loaded
```

The client is unable to connect to the above.

I think this is occurring because the URI is wrong the above output of mserver. Usually, while starting it using `monetdbd`, it automatically connects to the URI: `mapi:monetdb://127.0.0.1:50000/voc`

Can someone point me to how to change this URI while starting monetdb using `mserver5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do this. Have a look at the `dbfarm/merovingian.log` while starting it using `monetdbd`. The command is printed into the log file, change the threads parameter as needed.